# ActionBarSherlock TabNavigation

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have gotten my tabs up and running with Sherlock Fragments. So i have two tabs and two fragments. Now what i want is that when i click on a button in one of the fragments, I want another fragment to open up, but it should be inside the tab that contained the original fragment. Can anyone show me how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually Nested `Fragments` are not possible directly. I had a similar issue and but the `Fragment` to be shown was small and simple. So I just played with `setVisibility()` as `LinearLayout.GONE` and `LinearLayout.VISIBLE`

On the `Fragment` initialization, I hid the second layout and when I need to show the other fragment, I hid the first layout and showed the second layout. It worked great for me!

Comment: Nested fragments is possible from jelly bean.